# Calculating ratios in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, average, conditional-aggregation

I new to postgresql and I am trying do calculate a rate in a table like this:

```
class  phase
a      sold
b      stock
c      idle
d      sold
```

I want to calculate  the `total count of sold phases / total`  like this:

```
2/4 = 50%
```

i was trying:

```
with t as ( select count(class) as total_sold from table where phase='sold')

select total_sold / count(*) from t
group by total_sold
```

but the result is wrong.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVG()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT 100 * AVG((phase = 'sold')::int) AS avg_sold
FROM tablename;
```

The boolean expression `phase = 'sold'` is converted to an integer `1` for `true` or `0` for `false` and the average of these values is the ratio that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=326b6dbb711beebbad184337b7330647).